# Why transform external request class to internal request class before activity?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, service, rpc

What's the reason for transforming the **external** request class to **internal** request class before doing CRUD works?

Example Code:

```
public GetResponse(ExternalRequest request) {
    InternalRequest internalRequest = RequestContextBuilder.buildRequest(request);
    InternalResponse = solve(internalRequest);
}
```

Could anyone tell me why does not use the external request to do the activity directly? The detail elements are same for external and internal request class.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context? Without it, the best we can say is "decoupling".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more context it's hard to give an answer. But here are some reasons that I can imagine

- **Decoupling**

  The `solve` method has no dependency to the `ExternalRequest` class. It only depends on the `InternalRequest`. An `InternalRequest` might be build using a different input then `ExternalRequest`. So if you can just create an `InternalRequest` you can invoke the `solve` method.
- **Validation**

  Maybe the `RequestContextBuilder.buildRequest` does more then just creating another object. It might validate the `ExternalRequest`'s values before creating the `InternalRequest`. The author might want to express that an `InternalRequest` has only valid values. In this case it would make the implementation of the `solve` method easier, because the `solve` method could then rely on the fact that an `InternalRequest` is valid. It must not check all the properties.